# Entity detection details with Google DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I implemented a bot with IBM's Watson Assistant to solve and provide solution hints to a Sudoku puzzle provided the input matrix. I'm in the process of re-implementing this with Google DialogFlow ES. For hints you can ask for the value in a cell by row and column or you can ask if a the value in a given cell is x. The bot can handle both cardinal and ordinal numbers. Because the input can come row first or column first and can be asked with the possible cell value first (is 5 the value in the first row last column) or last (is the answer to penultimate column row 5 6) I need to know where the in the input text the entity was detected in order to determine the order of the entities. The Assistant API gives me this information, but I've been unable to determine how to get this info from the DialogFlow API. Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a pretty thorough investigation, I've concluded that Google DialogFlow will identify an entity, but will not return information regarding where the entity was found in the text response. I think this is a pretty serious limitation.